# merge function doesn't work in the cell of excel in C#

Tags: c#

I'm trying this code, but it doesn't work properly. My code is:

```
workSheet_range = worksheet.get_Range("V5", "V12");
workSheet_range.Merge(8);
```

My expected result is to do the merge operation in cells `V5` to `V12`.

[image]

Comment: In what way it doesn't work? What is the expected result and what do you get instead?

Comment: my expected result is merge operation in cells from V5 to V12. could you plz help me?

Comment: how it's work better???

Answer (score 0):

Please try it this way.

```
eWSheet.Range[eWSheet.Cells[1, 1], eWSheet.Cells[4, 1]].Merge();
```